# Globally indexing and updating array items from text inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing

So I have this code that renders a degree, two semesters at a time (class code, class name, and number of credits). The user sees two semesters and then has two buttons to either view the next two semesters or the previous two semesters. The user also has the option to edit some class names based on a conditional. The problem I am having is that only changes made to the first semester on the first page are being globally reflected. I need help with the indexing of the edited items and thus updating the global array 'itemArray'

Here is the code of the paragraph that renders the semesters and the onChange function:

```
itemArray.slice(page, page + 2).map((item, index) => (
                  <li key={index} style={{ display: 'inline-block', marginRight: '10px' }}>
                    <p>Semester {index + 1 + page}:</p>
                    <div className="semester-lines">
                      <div>
                      <p style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
  {item
    .map((items, index) => {
      
      const isEditable = items[1].toLowerCase().includes('elective') || items[1].toLowerCase().includes('cognate');

      return (
        <div key={index} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
          <span style={{ padding: '5px', margin: '5px', backgroundColor: '#323232', boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)', maxWidth: '100px', height: 'auto' }}>
            {items[0]}
          </span>
          {isEditable ? (
            <input
              type="text"
              defaultValue={items[1]}
              style={{ height: 'auto', minHeight: '40px', overflow: 'hidden', resize: 'none', padding: '5px', maxWidth: '300px', margin: '5px', color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#323232', boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)', textAlign: 'center' }}
              
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, page, index)}
            />
```

And here is the handleInputChange function:

```
const handleInputChange = (e, pageIndex, itemIndex) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setItemArray(prevItemArray => {
      const updatedItemArray = [...prevItemArray];
      const globalIndex = page + pageIndex; // calculate the global index
      updatedItemArray[globalIndex][itemIndex][1] = value;
      return updatedItemArray;
    });
  };
```

The current state of the code is that only edits made to some of the semesters are globally reflected. Edits made to other semesters are not only not being globally reflected but they are effecting some of the other editable fields on other pages that might share the same index within their respective semester. Here is an example of how the semesters are displayed:

| Semester 1 | Semester 2 |
| --- | --- |
| ECE 101 , Intro to Engineering , 3 | NULL , Editable Field , 3 |
| NULL. , Editable Field. , 3 | ENG 101 , Intro to English , 3 |

And then the user has the option to navigate to the next 2 semesters or the previous 2 semester (if there are)